# Django Inline model frontend

Tags: django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-class-based-views

I need to have four file fields for my model so i am using Django inline model for that. I also need to create a model for with all thode fields so that the user can fill out the form and i am using Class based views- CreateView for that. However i do not know how to get the file fields in my model form.

Models.py

```
class Product(models.Model)

name= models.Charfield(maxlength=50)
city= models.Charfield(maxlength=50)
state=model.Charfield(maxlength=50)
year=models.Integerfield(blank=True, null=True)

class ProductAttachment(models.Model)

attachment = models.ForeignKey(Product,    related_name='attachment')
appendix_a= models.Filefield(verbose_name='Appendix A')
appendix_b= models.Filedield(verbose_name='Appendix B')
Other = models.Filefield()
```

Admin.py

```
class ProductInline(admin.StackedInline)
    model=ProductAttachment


class ProductAdmin(admin.modelAdmin)
    inlines= [ProductInline,]
    model=Product
admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

forms.py

```
class ProductForm(models.form):
    class Meta:
        model=Product
        fields='__all__'
```

Views.py

```
class ProductCreateView(CreateView):
    model=Product
    form_class = ProductForm
```

However i do not know how to get all the filefield in the form. Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code the model for your ProductForm and ProductCreateView is Product, which does not contain any FileFiled. You need to create form/view for ProductAttachment as well.